# Cookies are blocked by Brave when using keycloak

Tags: javascript, keycloak, cross-domain, brave, keycloak-js

I have a running Keycloak instance on `auth.example.com` and my app is running on `example.io`.

Brave Shield is blocking CORS cookies, so the cookie is not sent to the `/protocol/openid-connect/token/` and therefore I get a 400 result.

What is the best solution do deal with this problem?
a) I catch the 400 call and inform the user to allow CORS cookies?
b) I host the keycloak instance on the same domain
c) I use another approach than cookies for this

C sounds insecure when you store the cookie only in localstore without the option http only
B will not work in the future when I have other applications that want to interact with the IAM

so the only option I think is A (which works, but is not userfriendly), isn't it?

Comment: What cookie? Which domain sets it and how? And to which requests do you expect the browser to attach the cookie in question?

Comment: @jub0bs to receive a valid token the client (example.io) will send the refresh token as a cookie to the keycloak endpoint (auth.example.com). But since this one is hosted on another domain, brace shield will block to attach the refresh token to the request

Comment: @cre8 Hello! did you find solution with keycloak js?

Comment: @quit haven't checked it any further